# Use react native components in Android app without creating a new Activity

Tags: android, react-native

I'm looking at using react-native components across mobile platforms (iOS and Android). The only approach I've seen for adding a react-native component to an Android app is to create an activity that extends `ReactActivity`.

Is there any way of adding/using react-native components at a lower level of granularity, such as a `View`?

Comment: I'm actually looking for a similar thing, the only solution I've found so far is this fragment component: [react-native-android-fragment](https://github.com/hudl/react-native-android-fragment)
It's not a View, but at least a smaller logical unit to deal with.

Comment: Did you achieved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to extend the `ReactActivity` class. But: If you don't, your activity must do certain things that `ReactActivity` would otherwise do for you. In particular, you must forward some life-cycle events to the [`ReactInstanceManager`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactInstanceManager.java):

- From `onPause`, forward to `reactInstanceManager.onHostPause`;
- From `onResume`, forward to `reactInstanceManager.onHostResume`;
- From `onDestroy`, forward to `reactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy`, and unmount your react application.

...and so on. See the source code for [`ReactActivity`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivity.java) and (in particular) [`ReactActivityDelegate`](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/ReactActivityDelegate.java) (which does most of the heavy lifting) for details.

(Never mind `ReactFragmentActivity`, which has been deprecated.)

Comment: Do you know of any open source example?